# Accessing a Comboboxedit in a GridControl

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a Gridcontrol that contains a comboboxedit.
The question is how to access it in the code-behind

The XAML

```
<dxg:GridControl x:Name="gridEntree" Margin="0,338,3,0" IsEnabled="True" GotFocus="gridEntree_GotFocus"  >
        <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            <dxg:GridColumn  FieldName="CODE_MAT" Header="Materiel" >
                <dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="cmbmat" ItemsSource="{x:Static my:ds_stock.Data}"
                           DisplayMember="NOM_APPAREIL" ValueMember="CODE_MATERIEL"
                            SelectedIndexChanged="cmbmat_SelectedIndexChanged"  />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </dxg:GridColumn.EditTemplate>
            </dxg:GridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, the `Name` property of a control used to edit cell values, **must be** set to `"PART_Editor"`. 
Then you can use the View's [ShowEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_ShownEditortopic) event to access editor after it really shown within Grid's cell:

```
void view_ShownEditor(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.EditorEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "CODE_MAT") {
        var cmbmat = (ComboBoxEdit)e.Editor;
        // do something (e.g. subscribe events)
    }
}
```

After the editor has been closed, a View fires the [HiddenEditor](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridViewBase_HiddenEditortopic) event - you can handle this event to dismiss some changes(e.g. unsubscribe from editor events).

Related examples:
[How to provide data for the ComboBoxEdit within a grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1850)
[How to: Use Custom Editors to Edit Cell Values](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6652)